# How to remove errors and commands displaying in command line window?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Based on several articles on the internet I have written a batch script that:

- scans defined location looking for .png files,
- creates path to the new location for each file (..\first 4 characters of filename\first 9 characters of filename)
- moves files to the new location

The script works fine, however I would like it to stop displaying errors and commands in command line window and display "PROCESSING..." instead? I have tried echo off, >nul and 2>nul with no success.

Here's the script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cls

pushd E:\Archiwum\
for /f "tokens=*" %%1 in ('dir /a-d /b E:\Archiwum\*.png') do (
    set filename=%%1&set dirname=!filename:~0,4!\!filename:~0,9!

    if not exist E:\Archiwum\!dirname! (md E:\Archiwum\!dirname!)
    move %%1 E:\Archiwum\!dirname!\
)
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider it "running fine", as long as you try "it to stop displaying errors". *Which* errors do you get (and for which line(s))?

Comment: Maybe more appropriate would be "command OR errors". I didn't observe any errors (maybe in case of duplicates, however in this situation I don not have any). What I really get in a command window is whole command with final result ("1 file(s) moved.").

Comment: Command repetition is turned off by `@echo off`. `x file(s) moved` isn't an error, but a success message. You can supress it with `>nul`: `move "%%1" "E:\Archiwum\!dirname!\" >nul`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally the solution was to combine your suggestion with putting @ECHO OFF again before for loop. Any ideas why?

Comment: no. According to your code, you turn `echo off` at the very start of the script and you don't turn it `on` again anywhere. (excect you do it somewhere but didn't show the full code)

Comment: Instead of just redirecting error messages to the NUL device, you should really strive to make a robust script where factors which could result in an error are accounted for first. You've already done it once, when you checked for the existence of the directory name before creating it, (you could have just made it and redirected STDERR to NUL)_. For instance, you should really know what the current directory is and if the intended working directory is valid or exists before switching. What if there aren't any `.png` files in that directory? _(should you have checked first?)_.

Comment: Additionally, because you are splitting a filename at four characters and unlikely as it my be, you may wish to check that those four characters aren't disallowed folder names, _(`COM1 .. 9` or `LPT1 .. 9`)_ too!

Comment: Great suggestion however I have full control over the folder content and therefore there may only contain files of the specific filename structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick rewrite of your script

```bat
@Echo Off
If Exist "E:\Archiwum\*.png" (CD /D "E:\Archiwum") Else Exit /B
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ClS
For %%A In (*.png) Do (Echo Processing %%A
    Set "filename=%%~nA"
    Set "dirname=!filename:~,4!\!filename:~,9!"
    If Not Exist "!dirname!\" MD "!dirname!"
    If Exist "!dirname!\%%A" (Echo Name conflict %%A already exists.
    ) Else Move "%%A" "!dirname!" > Nul)
```

You need to be careful of spaces in your file names in order to prevent having directory names with trailing spaces as well as the other things I mentioned in my comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your feedback. I made two modifications to your solution and now it works just fine.

```
@Echo Off
If Exist "C:\Archiwum\*.png" (CD /D "C:\Archiwum") Else Exit /B
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
ClS
@Echo Processing...
@Echo Off
For %%A In (*.png) Do (
    Set "filename=%%~nA"
    Set "dirname=!filename:~,4!\!filename:~,9!"
    If Not Exist "!dirname!\" MD "!dirname!"
    If Exist "!dirname!\%%A" (Echo Name conflict %%A already exists.
    ) Else Move "%%A" "!dirname!" > Nul)
```

1. I added second @Echo Off - without it commands from for loop where still shown in command window.
2. I moved @Echo Processing as I wanted it to be shown only once with all of the operations done in the background.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: `Echo`ing was turned off on the first line, unless there was a specific command after it `Echo On`, _(and there isn't)_, there is absolutely no way that you'd need to turn `Echo`ing `Off` again! Moving the `Processing...` string is fine, however, there's no need to prepend it with `@`, because `Echo`ing is already `Off`.